# PRIORVALUE formula

Tags: workflow, formula

I need a formula where if the custom field (type:currency) is not edited while the record is edited and saved, the custom field value should become zero otherwise it should hold the new value which is entered while record is edited. 
I think this can be done with (`PRIORVALUE` function) but i can't work out the logic.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to populate a new or previous value? You've mentioned `PRIORVALUE` formula and it's used to get the prior value of changed field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at a workflow on the SObject the currency field belongs to.

The condition formula should evaluate upon 
`created, and any time it's edited` and would look something like

```
AND(
    (!ISCHANGED(CurrencyField)),
    (CurrencyField != 0)
    )
```

Then you can add an update action and set the CurrencyField to 0

```
CurrencyField=0
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but the workflow will need to fire when `created, and any time it's edited`. This is because you can't use `ISCHANGED()` with a `subsequently meet criteria` workflow rule. I would also add an entry criteria item for `(CurrencyField != 0)` to avoid running the rule when it just stays at zero.

Comment: @ Jeremy Nottingham thank you for the suggestions, I've just edited the post

Comment: This is more complex as you would think - 2 worklows are needed: one to set 0 value, and another to populate the new value of `CurrencyField`. But even having these two, somehow you have to track when edit accured by the user and not by any type of automation (assuming this was in his requirements)